# Facing issue with angular ui-router 1.0.5 and angular 1.6.5 in IE11 browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router-extras

ui-router is causing an issue in the IE11 browser, Everything is working fine in chrome, firefox, and even IE10.

getting following error in the browser console.

```
SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TestApp due to:
TypeError: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
   at _extend (https://example.com/scripts/vendor.09a8eb90.js:100012:9)
   at Anonymous function
```

I'm pasting the ui-router code here where exactly causing an issue.

```
function _extend(toObj) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var obj = arguments[i];
        if (!obj)
            continue;
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            toObj[keys[j]] = obj[keys[j]];
        }
    }
    return toObj;
}
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js

Any guesses of why this happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The current version of angular-ui-router is 1.0.11. Just briefly looking at the change logs I see at least 5 IE 11 issues addressed in the interim releases.

Comment: Also your title says 1.0.5 and your cloudflare link is to 1.0.3. Which is it?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in both versions.